# How can I insert into a table after a new Devise user has been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails app and I need to insert into a separate table after a new user has been created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rails callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  after_create :insert_into_table

  private

  def insert_into_table
    # insert here
  end
end
```